# How to include punctuation and white space in Vigenere Cipher [Python]

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, caesar-cipher, vigenere

I am trying to do a Vigenere Cipher decrypter. The message gets decrypted with the current code that I have written. However, it does not take punctuation and whitespace into consideration. How do I make it consider these two components? Below is my code:

```
vigenered_message = 'dfc jhjj ifyh yf hrfgiv xulk? vmph bfzo! qtl eeh gvkszlfl yyvww kpi hpuvzx dl tzcgrywrxll!'

keyword = 'friends'

def vigenere_decrypt(encrypted_vigener, keyword):
    keyword_length = len(keyword)
    keyword_as_int = [ord(i) for i in keyword]
    encrypted_vigener_int = [ord(i) for i in encrypted_vigener]
    plaintext = ''
    for i in range(len(encrypted_vigener_int)):
        value = (encrypted_vigener_int[i] - keyword_as_int[i % keyword_length]) % 26
        plaintext += chr(value + 65)
    return plaintext

print(vigenere_decrypt(vigenered_message, keyword))
```

This offset of this should be: 'YOU WERE ABLE TO DECODE THIS? NICE WORK! 
 YOU ARE BECOMING QUITE THE EXPERT AT CRYPTOGRAPHY'

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
vigenered_message = r'dfc jhjj ifyh yf hrfgiv xulk? vmph bfzo! qtl eeh gvkszlfl yyvww kpi hpuvzx dl tzcgrywrxll!'

keyword = 'friends'

def vigenere_decrypt(encrypted_vigener, keyword):
    keyword_length = len(keyword)
    keyword_as_int = [ord(i) for i in keyword]
    encrypted_vigener_int = [ord(i) for i in encrypted_vigener]
    plaintext = ''
    for i in range(len(encrypted_vigener_int)):
        if vigenered_message[i].isalpha():
            value = (encrypted_vigener_int[i] - keyword_as_int[i % keyword_length]) % 26
            plaintext += chr(value + 65)
        else:
            plaintext += vigenered_message[i]
    return plaintext

print(vigenere_decrypt(vigenered_message, keyword))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
YOU WERE ABLE TO DECODE THIS? NICE WORK! YOU ARE BECOMING QUITE THE EXPERT AT CRYTOGRAPHY!
```

Just a sidenote, you should assign string to a variable in raw format otherwise characters like `\`,`"`,`'` inside your string, can create interruptions in the flow of program.

**USE THIS:**

```
vigenered_message = r'dfc jhjj ifyh yf hrfgiv xulk? vmph bfzo! qtl eeh gvkszlfl yyvww kpi hpuvzx dl tzcgrywrxll!'
```

**NOT THIS:**

```
vigenered_message = 'dfc jhjj ifyh yf hrfgiv xulk? vmph bfzo! qtl eeh gvkszlfl yyvww kpi hpuvzx dl tzcgrywrxll!'
```